# OnActionExecuted get status code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api

Is there a way to get the HTTP status code from MVC action from `OnActionExecuted`, without using the session variables?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve  ?

Comment: Is it necessary use `OnActionExecuted`? Can be used `OnResultExecuted`?

Comment: I needed to get status of response to be able to log it in the API logging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to access it. Mainly via the `ActionExecutedContext` which inherits from `ControllerContext`

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) {
    var statusCode = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463634/actionfilter-response-statuscode-is-always-200 - "ActionFilter Response.StatusCode is always 200". Need to use `context.Result` instead.