# ActionFilter Response.StatusCode is always 200

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to setup an action filter that only does something if the `StatusCode` of the `HttpContext.Response` is 302.

I would expect to be able to do this in the `OnActionExecuting` method, but the `StatusCode` is always `200`.

`ActionFilter` code:

```
public class CustomFilter : IActionFilter
{
   public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // do some setup
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status302Found)
        {
            // never get here
        }
    }
}
```

My `Action` method:

```
public IActionResult Redirect()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

And registering the `ActionFilter` in `startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(
    IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(
        options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CustomFilter());
        });
}
```

I have checked in the browser and it is correctly returning 302 and doing the redirect. I have also tried using the `IAsyncActionFilter` interface but had the same problem.

How can I apply my `ActionFilter` to (*only*) a redirected response?

And why is this not working as is?

**EDIT**: Whoops I had them the wrong way round. Actually I am still getting this issue though...

Comment: try your  code in executed instead of Executing (which called first), It must work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking at the status code of the response before response is actually generated. `OnActionExecuting` is [called before](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx) the action is executed, so no status code is set yet. [Default value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponsewrapper.statuscode(v=vs.110).aspx) for status code is 200, and that's what you see.

To be able to see the actual status code other actions have assigned to the response, you need to look at `OnActionExecuted`, which [runs after](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuted(v=vs.118).aspx) the action.

**Update.**

Another issue might be the fact that in Core framework action filter runs before and after the action is executed. So the response is not processed yet, and status code is not set in the http response object.

The proper method for your use case [seems to be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.0) `IResultFilter.OnResultExecuted`

Comment: Ahh dammit, I had them the wrong way round. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: @jag, are your types correct? you have `ActionExecut_ing_Context` for `OnActionExecut_ed_` and vice versa

Comment: Ahh sorry yes, no compiler to complain at me in stackoverflow editor!

Comment: @jag, that's weird. Works for me, and worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42444170/728795) too. Are you applying the filter correctly?

Comment: I've added where I register the `ActionFilter` in startup. It looks like that question isn't using aspnet-core, could that explain the discrepancy?

Comment: How is this even an answer to this question????!!!!! The status code is always 200 even in `OnActionExecuted`. This answers NOTHING.

Comment: @AradAlvand it was the update that fixed it for me - specifically using a `ResultFilter` instead of `ActionFilter`. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#filter-types

Answer (score 5):

You can attempt to convert your `ActionExecutedContext.Result` object to `ObjectResult` and retrieve `StatusCode` from it.

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    var statusCode = (context.Result as ObjectResult)?.StatusCode
}
```

Comment: This actually worked for me in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1 (in my OnActionExecuted method):

`var statusCode = (context.Result as StatusCodeResult)?.StatusCode ?? 200;`

Comment: @BobTabor Careful with this - return BadRequest(), return Forbid(), and exceptions might cause this to not work as you expect.

Comment: Better would be to try and cast it to an `IStatusCodeResult`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int? statusCode = null;
ObjectResult result = context.Result as ObjectResult;
statusCode = result?.StatusCode;

if (statusCode == null)
{
    StatusCodeResult statusResult = context.Result as StatusCodeResult;
    statusCode = statusResult?.StatusCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answers, in order to avoid as or cast, you can just use reflection

```
PropertyInfo pi = context.Result.GetType().GetProperty("StatusCode");
int httpCode = -1;
if (pi != null && pi.CanRead && pi.PropertyType == typeof(int)) httpCode = (int)pi.GetValue(context.Result);
```

So if **StatusCode** property is present, it will be read no matter what's the underlying result class type.